# Operating with DateTime::diff() inside a While with mysql records

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, diff, datediff

I´m currently working in a client payment list which i get from a mysql table.

im currently doing this

```
while($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){


            $texto .='</tr> <td>' . $fila['FctaTTipoDocumID'] . ' </td>
             <td>' .
         $fila['FctaLetra'] . '</td>
         <td> ' .
         $fila['FctaCentroEmision'] . '</td>
         <td> ' .
         $fila['FctaNroDocumento'] . '</td>
         <td>' .
         $fila['FctaCuota'] . "</td>
         <td>" .
         $fila['FctaImporte'] . "</td>
         <td>" .
         date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fila['FctaFechaVto'])) . "</td>
         <td>" .
         date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fila['FctaFechaAplicado'])) . '</td>
         <td></td></tr>';

         }
```

and then, i print the results like this

```
echo '<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4"><b>DOCUMENTO</th>
    <th>CUOTA</th>
    <th>IMPORTE</th>
    <th>VENCIMIENTO</th>
    <th>APLICADO</th>
    <th>DIFERENCIA</th>
  </tr>';
echo  $texto;
echo '</table>';
```

that works fine, just as i want.

now in the empty column, just next to **date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fila['FctaFechaAplicado']**
i need to show the days of difference between the two date rows ( FctaFechaAplicado and FctaFechaVencimiento)

as far as i know i have to use DateTime::diff(), i tried it in an empty document with defined vars just like this

```
    <?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2015-01-14');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-01-20');
$interval = $vencimiento->diff($aplicado);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
?>
```

it works just as i want, but i dont know how to integrate it in the while.
I tried a lot of different things and i don't know what else I can do.

appreciate your help
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you could use this :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2015-01-14','2015-01-20');
```

The output of this query will be :

> -6

So if you do not want any negative number change the two dates.

Comment: the problem is that i need to do the same operation for every row. that dates are just for test purposes.

Comment: You can create subquery where the date is and get the value from the database

Comment: thank you for your answer. i follow your advice and edit the query. Now works. Thanks!

Comment: If it did work I'm happy to help you. Accept if it was helpful